# React handle state in multi-step form

Tags: forms, reactjs

I'm trying to create a multi-step form on React.

For now, I had a one step form that would just simply render the component and show another component once the form was submitted.

This can be found on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Kotoriii/cecf942e2f15899a83be6686a9cae228) (apologies for the indentation, Github would always screw it over).

How can I handle the state of a multi-form form, if I want to have a let's say parent component `Form.js` render each form step like

`Form.js -> Step1 (Child of Form) -> Step2 (Child of Step1) -> etc?`

I've tried various NPM modules, but they do not seem to get along or work.

Is there a way I can get the state of all the Steps in the Parent Form Component, so that I can submit the data from there (and also validate each Step and reset the state after successfully submitting the form)?

This is the current one-step state code

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   phone: "",
   firstname: "",
   lastname: "",
   disabled: false,
   successIsVisible: false
  }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(name, value){
  let state = this.state;
  state[name] = value;
  this.setState({state});
}
```

Example input

```
<input id="lastname" className="form-control" placeholder="Your last name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'lastname')} name="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} />
```

Comment: There are tabs and spaces in that gist. Github renders tabs as a certain number of spaces. You can override the number of spaces that it uses for a tab character by passing `?ts=x` where x is the number of spaces to use. Your gist looks better when tab size is set to 2 spaces https://gist.github.com/Kotoriii/cecf942e2f15899a83be6686a9cae228?ts=2

Answer (score 1):

You can up childrens `state` to parent component with callbacks:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            childsState: null
        }
        this.getChildState = this.getChildState.bind(this);
    }
    getChildState(childrenName, childrenState){
        this.setState({childrenName: childrenState}); //with click Save button in FirstChildren you will get state of this component
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <FirstChildren getChildState={this.getChildState}/>
        )
    }
}

class FirstChildren extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
        this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
    }
    saveData(e){
        this.setState({data: e.target.value})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" onBlur={() => this.saveData(e)} />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.getChildState("firstChildsState", this.state)}> Save </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not understanding the getChildState method. How can I obtain a specific state/value from an input in a child? What if a child has many inputs with state?

Comment: @Doge, in my variant, i'm saving the value of one input to the `state`(child's). Then with click on the button, i'm sending all `state` of component up to the `parent` as argument to the callback function. If you have many inputs, you need to save all values to the `state` of the `child` and send this state up too.

Comment: I really thank you for your help! However, I'm having a hard time grasping how you would send more than one input's state up and how it would also work with another child as well.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3221/), in `console.log` in the `parent` you can see values of all inputs of the child.